# Setting up .xml to load .dvb plugin on AutoCAD startup

Tags: xml, autocad, dvb

I am trying to set up a .bundle folder to load a series of plugins I've designed for AutoCAD. One of these plugins is a .dvb file so in the PackageContents.xml I have the following XML code

```
    <ComponentEntry AppName = "" Version = "2014.1" ModuleName = "./Contents/Windows/WindowsDoors.dvb" AppDescription = "" PerDocument ="True" LoadOnAutoCADStartup="True">
      <Commands>
        <Command Local="CSC" Global="CAD_STANDARD_CREATOR" />
        <Command Local="CSB" Global="CAD_STANDARD_BLOCK" />
        <Command Local="CSP" Global="CAD_STANDARD_PATH" />
      </Commands>
    </ComponentEntry>
```

When I start AutoCAD and try to run the corresponding plugin the command line tells me

```
Command: -vbarun
Macro name: RunMeWindowDoor
Macro not found.
```

It appears that AutoCAD is not finding the Macro even though I'm telling the XML file to load it in and I can't figure out what the cause of the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Far as I know the AutoLoader does not support dvb Files.

See the [Whitepaper Autoloader](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html)  quote:

> The AutoCAD Autoloader currently processes and recognizes these
>   settings:
>
> “Bundle“,“ARX“,“Lisp“,“CompiledLisp“,“Dbx“,“.NET“,“Cui“,“CuiX“,“Mnu“
>   and “Dependency“   “Dependency” is used where you have a module that
>   should NOT be processed by AutoCAD. An example would be say a
>   licensing DLL, or maybe a resource DLL.

You could Write an LSP that loads the dvb, and place that LSP file in the Autoloader, that might do the trick.

```
(defun C:CSC ()
  (vl-vbaload "WindowsDoors.dvb")
  (vl-vbarun "WindowsDoors.dvb!CAD_STANDARD_CREATOR")
)
```

etc.

Kind Regards,

Alain van Gaalen

Comment: Your method worked but now I'm getting a new issue. Instead of saying Macro not found it says Execution Error. Any thoughts?

Comment: No not really, Sorry. An execution error most of the time is an error in Your dvb.  Does it run when you manually load it in AutoCAD?